# I screwed up a dual boot (Windows 7 + Ubuntu 14.04.1) so bad that no OS will load and I had to buy Windows again

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows, windows-7

So heres what happened: I had Windows 7, partitioned so that 64GB of unallocated space would be used to install Ubuntu side by side Windows 7. My live CD booted up and gave me the error message: Could not open "\EFI\BOOT\fallback.efi": 14

**However,** it still loaded and gave me a few options.
->Try Ubuntu without installing.
->Install Ubuntu
->Install OEM (for Manufacturers)
->Check disk for defects

**I should note here before I get further in, that it said it detected no operating systems on my PC and I had to use the "something else" option from the installer.**

I then ran into another problem. My hard drive was partitioned multiple times, (The main, local C:\ drive, "HP TOOLS" and "RECOVERY" and the System Reserved partition. I also had some weird listing that said it was only a megabyte. I deleted it. HP had set these partitions up. (This is a laptop, not a custom made PC.) I realized since the limit for partitions is 4, I was getting the "unusable" error because I couldn't have more than four partitions. I wanted to have one for "/home", one for "/", and one for "swap" or "swap area". I transferred over the HP TOOLS files to the main C:\ drive. I stupidly did not copy the recovery over, I just deleted it. So then I deleted the partitions made by HP, and put the partitions back into the main drive, as to be able to create more for Ubuntu. So FINALLY, after hours of work, (and no backups, because I'm an idiot,) I was able to create partitions for "/" and "swap" But not a separate partition for "/home" because the system reserved partition and main C:\ took up two out of four partitions already. But at least I had two for "swap" and "/" So I install Ubuntu. Everything is going great! The install finished and I was told that it needed to restart. Heres where everything messed up. I reboot and am greeted with this long error message:

"
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
 - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
   - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
   -Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
 -Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; 1s /dev)
ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/89313593-abaf-4f90-add3-496f84d6b339 does not exist
Dropping to a shell!
BusyBox v1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs) -
"

If I press enter it just shows "(initramfs) - " over and over. I tried changing boot devices and only "EFI file" and Disk drive are listed. I tried to restore my PC in every way I was given but couldnt. Tried with a Win 8.1 install disk and it loaded but I didn't have a serial key so it wouldn't work. Tried to restore but I had deleted HP's restore. Tried to Reset the computer completely from the Win8.1 disk but it said "Unable to reset your PC. A required drive partition is missing." If I click "Refresh your PC" it says the drive where Windows is installed is locked. Unlock the drive and try again."
This might be because I'm trying to repair a Windows 7 PC with a Windows 8.1 disc. But who knows...?

Every time I start up the PC it just lists these options:
->Ubuntu
->Advanced options for Ubuntu
->System Settings

When I hit "Ubuntu" it shows a blinking underscore which eventually turns into the "Gave up waiting for root device" error message above.

When I hit "Advanced options for Ubuntu" it lists:
->"Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-44-generic"
->"Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-44-generic (recovery mode)"
->"Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0.32-generic"
->"Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0.32-generic (recovery mode)"

I've only tried the first two from the advanced options list and they both result with the "Gave up waiting for root device" error message.

When I hit "System Setup" it says:

"error: can't find command 'fwsetup'.
Press any key to continue."

Please help! What did I do wrong? I'm screwed. I lost all my files from the past 3 years... :(

Also, I need to know if the same serial key that will come with my new copy of Windows 8.1 will be able to install the OS more than once, in case I keep trying to dual boot and it keeps screwing up like this, and I need to keep installing it.

Comment: You were wrong when you assumed that it is only possible to have four partitions. It is true, but only for primary partitions. Instead of the fourth primary partition, you can create an extended partition which is nothing more than a container for as much logical partitions as you want.

Answer (score 2):

**Please order a Restore DVD from your manufacturer (HP) and the Windows product key will still be valid!** (Last time I did this, I only paid shipping and handling)

Then read this Q&A: [What's a good back-up strategy for 1 desktop PC?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) (You're definitely User type 4!)

Then follow the article here: [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Even though it's a Q&A about Windows 8, it applies to Windows 7 UEFI systems!

Comment: Fabby, thanks for the reply. So you're saying even though I'm gonna put Windows 8.1 on my Windows 7 laptop, it'll still be a Windows 7 UEFI? Also, thanks for the links, but I don't think I'm gonna order a restore dvd, unless that would get all my files back? Would it?

Comment: Where are you going to buy Windows 8.1? From HP?  Because if you've destroyed your *UEFI* partition, you need to restore that too!

Comment: How would I restore that?

Comment: Well, a **Restore DVD from HP** as per the answer, would be the easiest (and cheapest) way of restoring the entire PC.

Comment: Couldn't I just re install Windows? Would a restore dvd from HP get my files back? Sorry about all the questions, you're being very helpful.

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately, AskUbuntu is not a forum, and the maximum number of comments has been reached. If you want additional information: http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask

Comment: Wait will the restore DVD from HP get my files back or not?

Comment: You can install Windows 7 on UEFI??